# Need helping combining data from different rows and columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble getting my query to do what I would like. This is my first time trying something like this. Here is part of the table I am working with:

[image]

So the DLSEQUENCE column is grouped together by a series of questions asked, this would make one record. What I am trying to find out is the number of restraints by organization. The two organizations I'll call them ABC and DEF. For the RECODED_RESPONSE column, the 1 would be Yes and 2 would be No for the Restraint?. The hardest part for me is putting the data together that is on separate rows.  I would like two columns, ABC and DEF. Then under each column, the total of restraints for organization.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Field_Name = 'Organization' AND  Recoded_Response = 'ABC'
                  THEN Recoded_Response 
              END)   AS ABC
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Field_Name = 'Organization' AND  Recoded_Response = 'DEF'
                  THEN Recoded_Response 
              END)   AS DEF
  FROM DAILY_LOG_CUSTOM_DATA
 WHERE Field_Name = 'Restraint?' 
   AND Recoded_Response = 1
GROUP BY DLSEQUENCE
```

I was looking for something like this for an output:

[image]

Comment: Please share how your end result should look alike.

Comment: Added expected output

Comment: There are no 50 or 75 in your sample data.

Comment: I was just giving an example, the 50 and 75 would be the total of restraints for each of the organizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to find out is the number of restraints by organization.

Hmmm . . . Does a `join` and `group by` work?

```
select o.recoded_response as organization,
       sum(case when r.recoded_response = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as restraints
from DAILY_LOG_CUSTOM_DATA o left join
     DAILY_LOG_CUSTOM_DATA r
     on o.DLSEQUENCE = r.DLSEQUENCE and
        r.Field_Name = 'Restraint?'
where o.Field_Name = 'Organization'
group by o.recoded_response;
```

Comment: I think that the `join` will work. I didn't know that I could join the same table together. I just need to figure out how to remove the 2's and count the 1's for each organization.

Comment: Could you explain why chose to use a join on this? I know it works, just trying to understand it a little better.

Comment: @HopDevvil814 . . . The two choices are conditional aggregation and a `join`.  For two columns, a `join` is probably faster.  The conditional aggregation approach is nice because the performance is not based on the number of columns selected.